# redirect doesn't work with json_encode

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

hello everyone i start to create a small application using codeigniter, and i want to submit my form using json i have a problem when i add json_encode inside my function,   redirect() doesn't work i don't know why 
this is my code

```
public function login_validate() {
    if ($_POST) {
        $login = $this->users->access(array(
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'password' => md5($_POST['password'])
                ));
        if (!$login) {
            redirect('/home');
        }
        echo json_encode($this->data);
    }
}
```

how can i fix this problem

Comment: It does work. It's just you have some different anticipation of what it does than it does. You should better ask for how to achieve something instead of wondering about why some (more or less useless) combination of functions does not do what you want to do but you do not directly ask for.

Comment: You can't redirect the browser from an Ajax call.  If you want to do that your JS code will have to examine the response and decide if the browser should be redirected from the client side (e.g. window.location = 'xxx').

Comment: you should put exit() after redirect()

Comment: @Loken Makwana That still won't redirect the page, as drew010 already explained…

Answer (score 0):

You should really be returning a flag in your JSON response, and then if flag is set, use window.location to got to the desired page.

What you are doing is redirecting the AJAX call to a new page, not your browser.